# Using 'Group By' Twice in Sequel

Tags: sql, sequelpro

All, I'm using the following Sequel query...

```
select
u.full_name, u.id, sum(hit_count), tag_names
from MyTable as t
inner join MyUsers as u on u.id=t.user_id
where t.created_at >= '2015-1-01 04:00:00' AND t.created_at < '2015-2-01 04:00:00' AND tag_names like '%Tree%'
group by u.id
```

...to render a table of data that looks like this with about 1,000 rows:

```
| full_name    | id  | sum(hit_count) | tag_names                 |

| Fred Johnson | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Apple, Blue, Banana |
| Joe Smith    | 002 | 663            | Tree, Red, Pear, Yellow   |    
| Tina Cook    | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Berry, Red, Grape   |
| Kyle Cross   | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Berry, Red, Grape   |
```

However, because I know the finite number of primary color tags (e.g. Red, Blue, Yellow) available, is there a way to tweak my Sequel query to also group by primary color tag (and add a primary color tag column to my table) to render...

```
 | full_name    | id  | sum(hit_count) | tag_names                 | Primary_Color_Tag |

 | Fred Johnson | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Apple, Blue, Banana | Blue              | 
 | Joe Smith    | 002 | 500            | Tree, Red, Pear, Yellow   | Red               |  
 | Tina Cook    | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Berry, Red, Grape   | Red               |
 | Kyle Cross   | 001 | 1500           | Tree, Berry, Red, Grape   | Red               | 
 | Joe Smith    | 001 | 163            | Tree, Red, Pear, Yellow   | Yellow            |
```

I've found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145511/use-of-group-by-twice-in-mysql) on [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060163/using-max-and-group-by-twice) that have seemingly relevant solutions, but I've been unable to piece together their logic to reproduce the table I'm after.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is this *primary color tag* supposed to come from that you want to group by? You've provided the names of 4 columns (full_name, id, hit_count, and tag_names). Where does *primary_color_tag* magically appear from? (I'm presuming it's from within *tag_names*, but there's no consistency to the position in that list you're retrieving from.)

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, Ken. My thinking was that it may be possible to add a new column to the data table using something like this...
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(tag_names, ',', 1) as First_Tag` The problem with that particular code, though, is that the order of tag_names entries is unpredictable—e.g. the primary color tag could be second or it could be fourth...

Comment: However, I was hoping that my knowledge of the precise names I'm attempting to target (Blue, Red, Yellow) might mitigate the issue of inconsistent position somehow.

Comment: You're going to have extreme difficulty doing this and then doing a GROUP BY on that column. (At the very least, you're going to have to use a sub-query to generate your columns, and then a select from that sub-query to do the grouping, unless your DBMS has some super-power that will do this for you.) I personally would normalize the data (create a separate column for primary color, and populate it independently from primary_color_tag) if you need to use it selectively, and then you can easily add the separate `primary_color` column and group by it in addition to the other columns.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, Ken. Unfortunately, I only have viewing access to the two tables I'm querying (MyTable and MyUsers) so, unless I'm misunderstanding you, I'm unable to normalize the data in the way you suggest.

Comment: That's too bad; it would have been much easier. I'm afraid I can't help with Sequel or Ruby; I could have with plain SQL, but not with those specifically.