# How to not COUNT if a bunch of column meet some condition while GROUP BY twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20cf7a/1)**

I have a table `sample` like this

**SAMPLE's table**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status | id   |
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | 01   |
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   |
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   |
|          8 |                      4 |      2 | 01   |
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      3 | 02   |
|          7 |                      5 |      2 | 02   ||
|          7 |                      5 |      3 | 02   |
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
```

i want to `GROUP BY` column `id` and `COUNT/SUM` how many `id` when some column meet some condition. For making may question more well-known, First i will make the `id` into two section

**Id: 01**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status | id   |
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   |
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | 01   |
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   |
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   |
|          8 |                      4 |      2 | 01   |
```

**Id: 02**

```
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   |
|          7 |                      1 |      3 | 02   |
|          7 |                      5 |      2 | 02   ||
|          7 |                      5 |      3 | 02   |
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
```

Take a look at the `id : 01` section first. You could see for column `id_laporan` in `id : 01` section, it has id `3` and `8`, and beside `id_laporan`, there is column `id_laporan_rekomendasi`. For `id_laporan : 3` it has `id_laporan_rekomendasi`: `2` and for `id_laporan : 8` it has `id_laporan_rekomendasi`: `3` and `4`.

NOW, each row in column `id_laporan_rekomendasi`, have `status` ( a column beside of `id_laporan_rekomendasi` ). In short, what i explain before is just like these:

**Id_laporan:3**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------+------------------------+--------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 |
|          3 |                      2 |      2 |
|          3 |                      2 |      3 |
```

**id_laporan:8**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------+------------------------+--------+
|          8 |                      3 |      2 |
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 
|          8 |                      4 |      2 |
```

Each `id_laporan_rekomendasi` have `status`. For each different id in `id_laporan_rekomendasi` and on the right column, column `status`,  have at least one data `3`, not `2` or other numbers, it will count as `1` else, it will count as `0`

so for **Id_laporan:3** it count as `1`, for **Id_laporan:8** it count as `0` because even `**Id_laporan:8**` has two different id for column `id_laporan_rekomendasi` but column `status` have no data `3` then it count as `0`. For example, the table looks like this

**SAMPLE**

**id_laporan:8**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------+------------------------+--------+
|          8 |                      3 |      2 |
|          8 |                      3 |      3 | 
|          8 |                      4 |      3 |
```

Then it will count as `2` because for each `id_laporan_rekomendasi` which is different id, it will count as `1`. We could assume the table meet the condition ( as i explained before, above this sample ).that means for `**Id_laporan:3**` and `**Id_laporan:8**` according to my explanation, they have data `1` and `0`. after i count these, i have to `SUM` both of those (that `1` and `0`) data for column `id:01`. These method was same with `id:02`. so the expected output will looks like below.

**Other scenario**

So what happen if the status `3` have already in the middle of `id_laporan_rekomendasi` ? , the id will definitely skipped `status = 3` at the middle of `id_laporan_rekomendasi`. Actually, there is no a scenario where you can found two data `3` in the same `id_laporan_rekomendasi` . it will looks like this

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------+------------------------+--------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | // 01 : 0, because status = 2
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | // 01 : 1, calculation function works because status = 3
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | // 01 : 1, because status = 2
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | // 01 : 1, because status = 2
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : **Each different `id_laporan_rekomendasi` have only one data status = `3`, so there is no scenario where status = `3` were found twice in the same `id_laporan_rekomendasi` like below scenario**

**False scenario**

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status |
+------------+------------------------+--------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | // Data status = 3, okay, for id_laporan_rekomendasi = 2, i dont need to check for the rest of id_laporan_rekomendasi's status, good grief, i will skip to the next id_laporan_rekomendasi` maybe, i will check id_laporan_rekomendasi = 3 
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | // what is this... ther is no way...
|          3 |                      2 |      2 |
```

**This is the output that i expect for my case**

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | count        |
+------+--------------+
| 01   |      1       |     
| 02   |      2.      |
+------+--------------+
```

Why the result i expect is just like above tables, based from the first table, the calculation is should be like this:

```
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
| id_laporan | id_laporan_rekomendasi | status | id   |
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 0, because status 2
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 0, because status 2
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 0, because status 2
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 0, because status 2
|          3 |                      2 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 0, because status 2
|          3 |                      2 |      3 | 01   | // 01 : 1, at this point the calculation works because status 3
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 1, because status 2
|          8 |                      3 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 1, because status 2 
|          8 |                      4 |      2 | 01   | // 01 : 1, because status 2 
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   | // 02 : 0, because status 2 
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   | // 02 : 0, because status 2 
|          7 |                      1 |      2 | 02   | // 02 : 0, because status 2 
|          7 |                      1 |      3 | 02   | // 02 : 1, at this point the calculation works because status 3
|          7 |                      5 |      2 | 02   | // 02 : 1, because status 2  
|          7 |                      5 |      3 | 02   | // 02 : 2, at this point the calculation works because status 3
+------------+------------------------+--------+------+
```

I have tried like this query

```
SELECT id, count(id) from sample group by `id`
```

But the result will like below

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | count        |
+------+--------------+
| 01   |      7       |     
| 02   |      6       |
+------+--------------+
```

I know that i have to use `CASE` function inside `count` but i dont know how to do it with my complex table.

Comment: Please let us know sample output that you expect?

Comment: @SMA okay i have edited my question

Comment: You are on the right track with `case` inside `count`. Show the query you have tried. Maybe read this to better undestand that concept: https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter  (in "Conforming Alternatives" you will see the `case` trick)

Comment: "id:02 has no data 3 at least one for their status that's why it didn't have data." - But I see two rows with `id=02` and `status=3`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel ah yes... i am sorry let me fix that

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Okay fixed

Comment: Do you have a table which holds all unique IDs (01, 02, ..)?

Comment: From your example it's not clear if you want to count distinct values in `id_laporan_rekomendasi` per `id_laporan` or together.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel well i dont have table like your description

Comment: i think i need `sum` at the end of table, not `count`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i want to count `id_laporan_rekomendasi` per `id_laporan` after thatn i want to sum how many data that have been calculate before with `group by` column `id`, so i need to know how many `id_laporan_rekomendasi` per `id_laporan` per `id` for each column `id` that have status = 3, which column `status` as child column of  column `id_laporan_rekomendasi` and column `id_laporan_rekomendasi`  as column child of `id_laporan` and as column child of `id` ( sorry about my bad grammar, i dont how to explain that very well )

Comment: @PaulSpiegel okay ihave edited again my question, please take a look

Comment: Why would "8" have a status of 1?

Comment: which one ? i didnt see it @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay i found it what you mean, fixed (y)

Comment: It really looks like all you need is to count the rows with `status=3` per `id`. If this is the case - you couldn't explain it in a more complicated way ;-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel actually, i working this using `php` but i dont know how to solved this using `php`, so i think ineed to solved this using query... :')

Comment: @GordonLinoff can we used `HAVING` function ?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel my question is similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145511/use-of-group-by-twice-in-mysql, but instead i need to sum just like my expected result looks like

Comment: @GordonLinoff my question is similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145511/use-of-group-by-twice-in-mysql, but instead i need to sum just like my expected result looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks to **Gordon Linoff** and **Paul Spiegel** for the `DISTINCT` and `CASE` in `COUNT()` function, i really appreciate (y)

I know that there is still a bug on this code, but i least it help to improvise this answer myself

```
SELECT t1.id , sum(tot) from ( 
  SELECT id, id_laporan, id_laporan_rekomendasi, 
  COUNT(distinct case when status = 3 then 1 end) as tot
  FROM sample t1
GROUP by id_laporan_rekomendasi ) t1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Result

```
| id | sum(tot) |
|----|----------|
| 01 |        1 |
| 02 |        2 |
```

Here is the **[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20cf7a/28)**

Answer (score 2):

You want a conditional `count(distinct)`.  I think this is what you want:

```
select id, count(distinct case when status = 3 then id_laporan end)
from sample
group by id;
```

This counts the number of different `id_laporan` with a status of "3" for each `id`.

EDIT:

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results depend on ordering, but you do not have a column that specifies the ordering.  You need one.  If necessary, you could add one to the table as:

```
alter table add t_id int auto_increment;
```

But the resulting ordering might not be what you really want.

With such a column you can readily calculate cumulative number of "3"s for each `id`.  Here is a method using correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id and
              t2.? <= t.? and status = 3
       ) 
from t;
```

The `?` represents the column for the ordering. If you have a set of columns with the ordering, then that can be used as well.

Comment: if i change `count` with `sum` is it okay ?

Comment: it just return `1` for id `02`, it has to be `2` because there is `2` data `3` in column `status`

Comment: what's the meaning by `ordering` that `?` part ? i am not quite get it, could you explain that more ?

Comment: could you give me example with `?` part ?

Comment: @Gagantous . . . The `?` is a column that represents the ordering of the rows in the table, as explained in the answer.